# How to have a "select all" option on a v-select or v-combobox?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

How do we have a select all option for selecting everything in a `v-select` or a `v-combobox` ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? Maybe these 2 links could be of use.

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select

https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/zPdzOe

The last link showing the select all via codepen.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have a "select all" in there (see: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#examples, under #Multiple) I wanted it to have some sort of "select all" to select everything on the options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vuetify have no `Select all` option for `v-select`. But, you can do your own with a button and a method.

Like this :

**JS**

```js
methods: {
  selectAll(){
    // Copy all v-select's items in your selectedItem array
    this.yourVSelectModel = [...this.vSelectItems]
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<v-btn @click="selectAll">Select all</v-btn>
```

[CodePen with SelectAll Button](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaYzgY?editors=1011)

---

**EDIT v1.2** Vuetify added `prepend-item` slot that let you add a custom item before listing items.

> The v-select components can be optionally expanded with prepended and appended items. This is perfect for customized select-all functionality.

**HTML**

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selectedFruits"
  :items="fruits"
  label="Favorite Fruits"
  multiple
>
  <!-- Add a tile with Select All as Lalbel and binded on a method that add or remove all items -->
  <v-list-tile
    slot="prepend-item"
    ripple
    @click="toggle"
  >
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon :color="selectedFruits.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
    <v-list-tile-title>Select All</v-list-tile-title>
  </v-list-tile>
  <v-divider
    slot="prepend-item"
    class="mt-2"
  />
</v-select>
```

**JS**

```js
computed: {
  likesAllFruit () {
    return this.selectedFruits.length === this.fruits.length
  },
  likesSomeFruit () {
    return this.selectedFruits.length > 0 && !this.likesAllFruit
  },
  icon () {
    if (this.likesAllFruit) return 'mdi-close-box'
    if (this.likesSomeFruit) return 'mdi-minus-box'
    return 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'
  }
},

methods: {
  toggle () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.likesAllFruit) {
        this.selectedFruits = []
      } else {
        this.selectedFruits = this.fruits.slice()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[Code Pen with Select All prepend item](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRBomG?editors=1010)

[Vuetify Doc about Prepend and Append Slots in v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-slots)

Comment: This doesn't quite work anymore as is, but there is now a full example in the documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#append-and-prepend-item

Answer (score 0):

```
**HTML template**
   <v-select
     v-model="selectedItem"
     :items="items"
     item-text="name"
     item-value="id"
     hide-details
     multiple
     @change="handleSelectItem($event)">
      <v-checkbox>
       @change="handleSelectAllItems"
       v-model="selectAll"
       slot="prepend-item"
       hide-details
       label="Select All"
      />
     </v-checkbox>
    </v-select>
```

**Script tag**

```
data() {
  selectAll: false,
  selectedItem: [],
  items: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'item1'
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'item2'
    }
  ]
},
methods:{
    handleBondExpensesRequests() {
      this.selectAll = !!(
        this.selectedItem.length == this.items.length
      )
    },
    handleSelectAll(val) {
      this.selectedItem = val ? this.items : []
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue 3 but with the same idea, here is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

```js
  <template>
    <v-select
      chips
      multiple
      clearable
      density="default"
      variant="underlined"
      v-model="selList"
      :items="tplList"
      return-object
    >
      <template v-slot:prepend-item>
        <v-checkbox
          class="ml-4 text-body-2"
          v-model="isSelectAll"
          @click="toggleSelectAll"
          hide-details
          ripple
        >
          <template v-slot:label>
            <span class="text-body-2"> Select All </span>
          </template>
        </v-checkbox>
        <v-divider />
      </template>
      <template v-slot:label>
        <div>
          <v-icon class="mr-2">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
          <span>{{ label }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </v-select>
  </template>

  <script setup>
    import { ref, computed } from "vue";
    //a pinia store that contains your select data structure
    import useSelectStore from "@/stores/SelectStore"; 
    const { selList, tplList, icon, label } = defineProps([
      'icon',
      'label',
    ]);
    const { tplList, selList } = useSelectStore();
    const isSelectAll = computed(
      () => selList.length > 0 && selList.length === tplList.length
    );
    const toggleSelectAll = () => {
      !isSelectAll.value
        ? selList.splice(0, selList.length, ...tplList)
        : (selList = []);
    };
  </script>
```

Note `return-object` option in select tag. Use it depends on your sel/tpl list structure. If they are list of objects, use it. If they are a list of plain strings, remove it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add an "ALL" option into v-select. you can do it this way:

```
<v-select
   :items='[{text: "--ALL--", value:""}, ...myItems]'
    label='Select an item'
              outlined
></v-select>
```

Comment: You do know that when clicking --ALL-- should click all other items right, where is that?