# Select All functionality to select filtered items in vuetify combobox

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify combobox and the select all is working as expected as described in [How to have a "select all" option on a v-select or v-combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560020/how-to-have-a-select-all-option-on-a-v-select-or-v-combobox).

What I'm trying to achieve is - when I check the Select All, it should select all the filtered values from the list.

[image]

In this example, I've typed "Pha..." and what I'm trying to achieve is to get the filtered list to be returned.

The Combobox is as below -

```html
<v-combobox v-if="editedIndex == -1"
  label='Phase'
  v-model='editedItems.selected_values'
  :items='phases'
  item-value='pp_code'
  item-text='phasedetails'
  class="pl-2 pr-2"
  multiple
  chips
>
  <template v-slot:prepend-item>
    <v-list-item
      ripple
      @click="toggle(); editedItems.selected_values.length = phases.length;"
    >
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-icon :color="editedItems.selected_values.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">
          {{ icon }}
        </v-icon>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>
          Select All
        </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
    <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

The toggle function is as below -

```js
toggle () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    if (this.likesAllFruit) {
      console.log("Select all clicked")
      this.selectedFruits = []
      console.log("Typed value is ")
      console.log(this.editedItems.phase_code)
      console.log("Selected values ")
      console.log(this.editedItems.selected_values)
      this.alreadySelectedPhases.push(this.editedItems.selected_values)
      console.log(this.alreadySelectedPhases)
      console.log(this.phases.length)
    } else {
      this.editedItems.selected_values = this.phases.slice()
    }
  })
},
```

I'm not getting the typed value until the combobox is selected so that we can filter the list by the typed value and return.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea on how we can achieve it. Or if we have any inbuilt method for it.

Thanks in Advance.